# Самосоединение таблицы с исключением дублей

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задача. Есть таблица PC (model, speed, ram) из которой нужно выбрать пары моделей, которые имеют одинаковые speed и ram, но в результате не должны быть выведены записи которые соединены сами с собой и "обратные" пары (то есть не должно быть что вывелось Запись1-Запись2, а потом Запись2-Запись1).

Как избежать соединения записи с самой собой еще понятно, но вот как убрать обратные дубли не понимаю.

Мой вариант пока выглядит так:

```sql
SELECT A.model, B.model, A.speed, A.ram
FROM PC AS A JOIN PC AS B
ON A.model <> B.model 
AND A.ram = B.ram
AND A.speed = B.speed
```

Но он допускает обратные дубли.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A.model, B.model, A.speed, A.ram
FROM PC AS A JOIN PC AS B
ON A.model > B.model 
AND A.ram = B.ram
AND A.speed = B.speed
```

Comment: К вашему ответу следует добавить DISTINCT, тогда результат верный во во всех тестовых случаях. Почему пока не могу понять, но следует это отметить.

Comment: Вопрос ко всем: ответ выше правильный в полной мере, но только если имеется DISTINCT. Если нет, то запрос возвращает верный результат не во всех случаях. Почему? DISTINCT устраняет дубли, но тут дублей итак быть не может, так как в условии соединения имеется неравенство ключевых полей, то есть как минимум одно поле будет меняться каждую запись. Другое дело, что может такое быть, что условия выполнились несколько раз (например, имеется более одного совпадения на одну запись). Почему DISTINCT так тут зарешал???

Answer (score 2):

Например - в первом столбце всегда выводить меньшую модель, во втором - большую. И делать Distinct:

```sql
SELECT distinct case when A.model<b.Model then a.Model else B.Model end,
case when A.model<b.Model then B.Model else A.Model end, A.speed, A.ram
FROM PC AS A JOIN PC AS B
ON A.model <> B.model 
AND A.ram = B.ram
AND A.speed = B.speed
```

Comment: distinct не нужен

Comment: Нужен, иначе будут дубли: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f8f1/2

Comment: откуда они возьмутся?

Comment: Ну есть у нас пара 1 и 2. Мы по выборке получим (1,2), (2,1), перевернем в Case, получим (1,2),(1,2). В вашем варианте дублей не будет (и работать он будет быстрее, да).

Comment: ну да в вашем случае да distinct нужен